# I have Excel sheet with data of person multiple logins in a particular day i wish to seperate only one login per day in different row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Employee has logged in to the system 10 times on 02/07/23, 5 times in 03/07/2023, then 7 times next day and so on, I want to refine the data to get employee one login per day so that I can know on which date the employee was on leave.

As the employee has logged in multiple times in to the system each day it's difficult to find out on which day he was on leave as there is so much data, so I just want to refine his logins to one per day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Part of that clarification should indicate how your data is currently organised.

Comment: The `UNIQUE()` function will do what you ask. However the solution to the whole problem is described in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the missing dates in a column of dates as follows:

**Givens:**

- Column of login dates is Column A.
- Date range of interest is 3/1/2023 to 3/30/2023

First we need a list of all days in the month of March:

```
DATE(2023, 3, 1) + SEQUENCE(31,,0)
```

We will want to match that against the column of login dates and return the date if it is not matched. We can use the `LET` function to add clarity:

```
 LET(  DT
     , DATE(2023, 3, 1) + SEQUENCE(31,,0)
     , IF( ISERROR( MATCH( DT, $A:$A, 0 ) ), DT, "--" )
    )
```

Finally, we can wrap the whole thing in a `UNIQUE` and `SORT` to clean the output:

```
SORT( UNIQUE( LET(  DT
                   , DATE(2023, 3, 1) + SEQUENCE( 31,,0)
                   , IF( ISERROR( MATCH( DT, $A:$A, 0 ) ), DT, "--" )
                 )
            )
    )
```

**Sample Input:**

| Column A |
| --- |
| 3/1/2023 |
| 3/2/2023 |
| 3/3/2023 |
| 3/4/2023 |
| 3/5/2023 |
| 3/6/2023 |
| 3/6/2023 |
| 3/6/2023 |
| 3/9/2023 |
| 3/10/2023 |
| 3/11/2023 |
| 3/12/2023 |
| 3/13/2023 |
| 3/13/2023 |
| 3/15/2023 |
| 3/16/2023 |
| 3/17/2023 |
| 3/18/2023 |
| 3/19/2023 |
| 3/19/2023 |
| 3/19/2023 |
| 3/22/2023 |
| 3/23/2023 |
| 3/24/2023 |
| 3/25/2023 |
| 3/26/2023 |
| 3/27/2023 |
| 3/28/2023 |
| 3/29/2023 |
| 3/30/2023 |
| 3/31/2023 |

**Yields:**

| Result |
| --- |
| 3/7/2023 |
| 3/8/2023 |
| 3/14/2023 |
| 3/20/2023 |
| 3/21/2023 |
| -- |